# Android sharing on Google Plus

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

This code always causes ActivityNotFoundException

```
Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
                .setType(mime)
                .setStream(uri)
                .setText(shareText)
                .getIntent();

startActivity(shareIntent);
```

But Google+ App is installed on my phone and if I use a generic intent ACTION_SEND everything works fine.

HOW is sharing on Google+ from Android (with Google Play libraries installed) supposed to be done??

Do you know of any good example?

I don't want to use Login with Google+